# Catch arrow keys using TermCaps

Tags: c, termcap

I am currently working on a complete shell built in C.

I want to implement a bash history and navigation using arrows keys through my double linked list but I am having some troubles with TermCaps and properly 
setting up `read()` function.

Here is how I set up my terminal :

```
static int      set_terminal_mode(t_shell *shell, const int mode)
 {
   char          *term_name;

   if (mode == 0)
     {
       if ((term_name = getenv("TERM")) == NULL)
         return (-1);
       ioctl(0, TCGETS, &shell->term);
       shell->term.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
       shell->term.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
       shell->term.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;                                         
       ioctl(0, TCGETS, &shell->term_save);
       ioctl(0, TCSETS, &shell->term);
     }
   if (mode == 1)
     ioctl(0, TCSETS, &shell->term_save);
   return (0);
 }
```

I can catch when left or right key is pressed and then I use `\r` to erase the line (which doesn't really work) but the main problem is that I cannot use the return key anymore (only display `^?`)
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
       shell->term.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
```

turns off *canonical* mode, which [according to POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap11.html#tag_11_01_07) does several things including turning off the line-buffering, which includes special treatment of carriage return:

> In non-canonical mode input processing, input bytes are not assembled into lines, and erase and kill processing shall not occur.

and

> **`CR`**
>       Special character on input, which is recognized if the **`ICANON`** flag is set; it is the carriage-return character. When **`ICANON`** and **`ICRNL`** are set and **`IGNCR`** is not set, this character shall be translated into an **`NL`**, and shall have the same effect as an **`NL`** character.

If you want to read single bytes (for cursor-keys), you'll have to handle single-byte control characters such as carriage return (`CR`) and line-feed (referred to as `NL` or newline).

By the way, your example seems to have the saved/modified settings reversed: The call

```
     ioctl(0, TCSETS, &shell->term_save);
```

uses terminal settings saved in

```
       ioctl(0, TCGETS, &shell->term_save);
```

which is after you have already modified the terminal settings.